# 'Sign In with Google' in Firebase Auth not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

My dependencies in build.gradle (Module : app):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'
```

google services version
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

Login Method :

```
private fun launchSignInScreen() {
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build())
                    ).build(),
            SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Whenever I tap Sign in with Google and I select a Google Account I get a Toast message:

> An unknown error occured.

Yes, "Sign in with Google" is enabled in Firebase dashboard

What could be wrong how can i get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried to add this `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'`?

Comment: i don't used it, but i think your application should be have a ssh key in firebase project setting. Try to find information about it.